# Kubernetes - connect from Job to Pod

Tags: kubernetes, cassandra

I have a pod with a database running. My goal is to initialize the db with k8s Job using Helm Hooks.
I have managed to set up the Job with the schema script.

Unfortunately I have some issues with connecting from `command` of Job to the existing Pod.

Here's my error:

```
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")}]
```

On the Pod I have Cassandra container running, on my Job I'm using the following command:

```
command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "cqlsh -f /path/to/schema.cql"]
```

Do I have to define somehow the way to connect to the Pod? I have a Service with Cassandra running as well.

Comment: it seems it is trying to connect to cassandra host at localhost 127.0.0.1 , specify the correct cassandra host , you can use your cssandra svc FQDN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Helm hook creates a new pod as part of the hook.You can not use `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` to connect to a pod from another pod because they are in different network namespace. You should use the `<PODIP>:9042` or if the pod is exposed by a service then use the service name i.e `<service-name>.<namespace-name>.svc.cluster.local:9042`

Alternative to helm hook you can use an [initcontainer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) wherein you can use `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`.

Comment: Do you mean to use `cqlsh <PODIP>:9042 /path/to/schema.cql`?

Comment: I've tried both solutions you provided. With the PODIP I'm getting the same error, however, when I'm trying to use service-name path, cqlsh crashes.

Comment: update: when using service name path cqlsh cannot recognize the name. However, when I enter the container and execute the command with the service path it works.